# Time Machine fails to create backup without error

Tags: macos, time-machine

When I open the Time Machine dialogue through the shortcut in the menu bar, I click on "Backup Now" to create a new backup. As expected, the status updates go through the following stages:

```
Preparing Backup...
Found X changes...
Y% done (Z MB copied)
```

where X, Y, Z are positive and increasing numbers.

However, a new backup is never created: When I check the status after a while, it shows that the date of my latest backup has not changed ("Latest Backup to "[hard drive name]": January 29, 2023). There is no error that is raised during the process.

There has been no incident with my OS or the hard drive ever since the last successful backup that I can recall. I also cannot find any reports on the Internet that seem to resemble my problem.

How can I identify the cause and fix this issue?

setup:

- macOS 12.6.3
- MacBook Pro Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015
- SAMSUNG Portable SSD T5, Capacity 1T, 483 GB available, Format Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)

Comment: How long have you been using this specific external drive? Since before Monterey, Catalina? Monterey *will* use an existing HFS+ drive if it had been in use already, but if setting up a new drive it should be APFS.

Comment: Appreciate your time to respond. I purchased the external hard drive only in October 2021 and, according to the system profiler, updated to Catalina on 2020-06-27 (and to Monterey on 2021-12-04). So my answer is no, I did not use it before Monterey, Catalina.

Comment: Hmmm… then I wonder why it did not prompt you to reformat to APFS. This is what APple has to say about it - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh15139/12.0/mac/12.0 I'm not sure why your current issue is happening, as I guess once it's accepted the backup is on HFS, it ought to continue to accept it.

Comment: I may have manually formatted the new hard drive to Mac OS Extended before creating my first backup and/or chosen this format in the setup procedure simply out of ignorance, I cannot recall. In any case, my understanding is that Time Machine should still work with this format. Currently, I can't erase and reformat at this time given the lack of another hard drive.

Comment: I'm out of ideas really. I'd run Disk Warrior over it - but if you don't already own it, it's expensive for a one-off task, especially as it only works on HFS, not APFS disks. Otherwise, maybe try Repair in Disk Utility, at least see if it claims any issues [I have found over the years Apple's built-in 'disk fixer' to be completely useless compared to Disk Warrior, which was undisputed king in its time.]

Comment: I cross-posted in the Apple Community, but also did not get a satisfactory answer.  I'm too anxious to mess with this hard-drive without a backup of this backup. A spare hard drive is now on its way so I can safely erase and reformat this one. Setting up double backups has been on my to do list anyway. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: The problem persists even with my new hard drive, which has a APFS Encrypted format. My MBP has always been plugged in (with default battery preferences) and the external hard drive has not been unmounted during the process. This is frustrating.

Comment: All I can think to try is clear all local backups & see if that 'jogs its elbow' a bit - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340905/how-to-delete-all-local-timemachine-snapshots

Comment: There were no local backups on my disk, so this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: It seems that some file permissions caused the issue. I would have expected Time Machine to at least raise an error. To anyone experiencing a similarly odd behavior, look through the log files using `printf '\e[3J' && log show --predicate 'subsystem == "com.apple.TimeMachine"' --info --last 1h | grep -F 'eMac' | grep -Fv 'etat' | awk -F']' '{print substr($0,1,19), $NF}'`.

Comment: It turned out that there were permission issues with a few files (ones that are probably a decade old). I found these by looking through the Time Machine logs. Once they were fixed, I could backup again to the old and new external hard drive. It was frustrating that not even the logs tied the backup failure to the lack of permissions. I believe this was never an issue before because only recently I moved these files on to my laptop and thus became subject to Time Machine Backups.